# Appending nodes to linked list by reading from text file almost working

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, fstream

Good day everyone! I have a program where it has a linked list where each node has a string name and an int for the ID's for the respective names, the append, prepend, insertafter, delete and etc. functions work fine, but I need to implement so that it reads from a text file, sample:

[image: text file sample]

using this code

```
case 9:
        {
            file.open("Attendance.txt");
            while (!file.eof())
            {
                file>>node->attendeename>>node->key;
                attendance.appendAttendee(node);
            }
        cout << "imported\n";
        }
        break;
```

When I try to  run that option, it only appends the last line in the text file as a node, console:

[image: console]

Here is the full program code, the rest of the program was made through collaborations with friends and online resources, I do not claim it as my own

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//linked list node
class Node {
  public:
  int key;
  string attendeename;
  Node* next;
};


class LinkedList {
  public:
    Node * head;
    //default constructor
  LinkedList() {
    head = NULL;
  }
  //Have head point to the node
  LinkedList(Node * n) {
    head = n;
  }

  // Checks if node exists using key value 
  Node * keyAlreadyExists(int k) {
    Node * check = NULL;      
    Node * ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
      if (ptr -> key == k) //checks if k already exists as a key
       {
        check = ptr;
      }
      ptr = ptr -> next;
    }
    return check;
  }

  //Append a node to the end of the list
  void appendAttendee(Node * n) {
    if (keyAlreadyExists(n -> key) != NULL) //first checks if a node already exists with n -> key 
    {
      cout << "----- Node Already exists with key value : " << n -> key << ". Append another node with different Key value -----" << endl << endl;
    }
    else
    {
      if (head == NULL) //checks if list is empty
      {
        head = n;  //the node becomes the head of the list
        cout << "----- Node Has Been Appended -----" << endl << endl;
      }
      else
      {
        Node * ptr = head;
        while (ptr -> next != NULL) //traverses to the end of the list
        {
          ptr = ptr -> next;
        }
        ptr -> next = n;  // the current last node will now point to the passed node    
        cout << "----- Node Has Been Appended -----" << endl << endl;
      }
    }

  }
  // add node to the start of the list
  void prependAttendee(Node * n) {
    if (keyAlreadyExists(n -> key) != NULL) //first checks if a node already exists with n -> key 
    {
      cout << "----- A Node Already exists with key value : " << n -> key << ". Append another node with different Key value -----" << endl;
    }
    else  
    {
      n -> next = head; //makes node n point to the address of head
      head = n;
      cout << "----- Node Has Been Prepended -----" << endl << endl;
    }
  }

  // insert a node after a specific node in the list
  void insertAttendee(int k, Node * n) {
     if (head == NULL) //checks if their is already a node in the list
    {
      cout << "----- Attendance list is still empty, can't add after key-----" << endl << endl;
    } else {
    Node * ptr = keyAlreadyExists(k); //checks if the int k that is passed does exist inside the list
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
      cout << "----- No node exists with key value: " << k << " -----" << endl << endl;
    }
    else
    {
      if (keyAlreadyExists(n -> key) != NULL) //checks if the key in the new node to be added, already exists in the list
      {
        cout << "-----A Node Already exists with key value : " << n -> key << ". Append another node with different Key value -----" << endl << endl;
      }
      else
      {
        n -> next = ptr -> next; //makes the newly added node point to the node that the previous node was pointing to
        ptr -> next = n;  //links the node that has the chosen key point to the new node
        cout << "----- Node Has Been Inserted -----" << endl << endl;
      }
    }
  }
}

  // Delete a node that has the key int k
  void deleteAttendee(int k) {
    if (head == NULL) //checks if their is already a node in the list
    {
      cout << "----- Attendance list already empty. Cannot delete anymore -----" << endl << endl;
    } else if (head != NULL) {
        //checks if int k belongs to the key of head node
      if (head -> key == k) {
        head = head -> next; //makes head pointer point to the node after the head node 
        cout << "----- Attendee with key ID " << k << " deleted -----" << endl << endl;
      } else {
        Node * temp = NULL;
        Node * prevptr = head;
        Node * currentptr = head -> next;
        while (currentptr != NULL) {
            //checks if the key of currenptr is int k
          if (currentptr -> key == k) {
            temp = currentptr;
            //gets rid of the node of currentpr
            currentptr = NULL;
          } else {
            //moves on to the next node
            prevptr = prevptr -> next;
            currentptr = currentptr -> next;
          }
        }
        //checks if a node has been deleted
        if (temp != NULL) {
            //makes the previous pointer point to the node after the deleted node
          prevptr -> next = temp -> next;
          cout << "----- Attendee with key ID " << k << " deleted -----" << endl << endl;
        } else {
          cout << "----- Attendee doesn't exist with key ID " << k << " -----" << endl << endl;
        }
      }
    }

  }
  // update the info of a node with a specific key
  void updateAttendeeInfo(int k, string name) {
    //checks if a node with key int k exists
    Node * ptr = keyAlreadyExists(k);
    if (ptr != NULL) {
     //updates the data of the node
      ptr -> attendeename = name;
      cout << "----- Information Updated Successfully -----" << endl << endl;
    } 
      //output if no node contains the key int k    
      else {
      cout << "----- No Attendee has this key ID " << k << " -----" << endl << endl;
    }

  }

  // function to print the entire linked list
  void printAttendanceList() {
    //checks if the linked list contains any nodes
    if (head == NULL)
    {
      cout << "----- No attendees recorded in list -----";
    }
    else
    {
      cout << endl << "----- List of Attendees -----" << endl;
      Node * temp = head;
      //to print the key and data of every node in the list
      while (temp != NULL)
      {
        cout << "Name: " << temp -> attendeename << setw(7) << "ID: " << temp -> key;
        temp = temp -> next;
        cout << endl;
      }
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

  }
  
  
  //function to output the entire linked list to text file
  void backupAttendanceList()
  {
    ofstream file("Attendance.txt");
    Node * temp = head;
      //to print the key and data of every node in the list
      while (temp != NULL)
      {
        file << temp -> attendeename << setw(7) <<  temp -> key;
        temp = temp -> next;
        file << endl;
      }
      cout << "----- Attendance list backed up successfully -----" << endl << endl;
  }
  


}   ;

int main() {

  LinkedList attendance;
  int choice, id, nodekey;
  fstream file;
  string name;
  
  //menu screen
  do {
    //new node;
    Node * node = new Node();
    cout << "Welcome to the event! Please select option to do from the registration menu:" << endl << endl;
    cout << "1 - Add attendance" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Insert attendance on front of list" << endl;
    cout << "3 - Insert attendance after certain key ID" << endl;
    cout << "4 - Delete attendance by key ID" << endl;
    cout << "5 - Update attendance details by key ID" << endl;
    cout << "6 - Print list of attendees" << endl;
    cout << "7 - Clear screen" << endl;
    cout << "8 - Backup to text file" << endl;
    cout << "9 - Import from text file" << endl;
    cout << "10 - Exit Program" << endl << endl;

    cout << "Your Choice: "; cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;
    

    switch (choice) {
    
    //add attendance
    case 1:
      cout << "Add your attendance details. Please enter the following:" << endl 
      << "Key Data: "; 
      cin >> id;
      cin.ignore();
      cout << "Name: ";
      getline (cin,name);
      cout << endl;
      node -> key = id;
      node -> attendeename = name;
      
      attendance.appendAttendee(node);

      break;

    //insert attendance to top
    case 2:
      cout << "Insert attendance from top of list. Please enter the following:" << endl 
      << "Key Data: "; 
      cin >> id;
      cin.ignore();
      cout << "Name: ";
      getline (cin,name);
      cout << endl;
      node -> key = id;
      node -> attendeename = name;
      
      attendance.prependAttendee(node);
      break;

    //insert attendance after a certain node
    case 3:
      cout << "Insert attendance. After which key ID you want to be inserted? " << endl
      << "Key ID of attendee you want to insert after: ";
      cin >> nodekey;
      cout << "Add your attendance details. Please enter the following:" << endl 
      << "Key Data: "; 
      cin >> id;
      cin.ignore();
      cout << "Name: ";
      getline (cin,name);
      cout << endl;
      node -> key = id;
      node-> attendeename = name;

      attendance.insertAttendee(nodekey, node);
      break;

    //deletion of attendance
    case 4:

      cout << "Delete attendance. Please enter key ID to be deleted: ";
      cin >> nodekey;
      cout << endl;
      
      attendance.deleteAttendee(nodekey);
      break;
      
    //update attendance
    case 5:
      cout << "Update existing attendance. Please enter the following:" << endl
      << "Key Data: ";
      cin >> id;
      cin.ignore();
      cout << "Updated Name: ";
      getline (cin,name);
      cout << endl;
      
      attendance.updateAttendeeInfo(id, name);
      break;
    
    //print recorded list
    case 6:
      attendance.printAttendanceList();
      break;
    
    //clears console screen
    case 7:
      system("cls");
      break;
    
    //creates txt file  
    case 8:
        attendance.backupAttendanceList();
        break;
    
    case 9:
        {
            file.open("Attendance.txt");
            while (!file.eof())
            {
                file>>node->attendeename>>node->key;
                attendance.appendAttendee(node);
            }
        cout << "imported\n";
        }
        break;
    //exits the program
    case 10:
        cout<< "Now closing program" <<endl;
        exit(1);
        
    default:
      cout << "Invalid Option Number Entered, Enter Again:" << endl;
    }

  } while (choice != 10);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try shrinking the question down as much as possible using only code that is relevant to it. Like this everyone has to deal with 346 lines of code, while you probably know yourself, where the issue might be. (e.g. only in case 9, and we don't need to know the whole class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you are appending the same node repeatedly.

```
Node* node = new Node();
...
while (!file.eof())
{
    file>>node->attendeename>>node->key;
    attendance.appendAttendee(node);
}
```

Your code should create a new node for each item in the file, like this

```
while (!file.eof())
{
    Node* node = new Node();
    file>>node->attendeename>>node->key;
    attendance.appendAttendee(node);
}
```

I don't think I'm out of order in saying that you probably have multiple problems in this code (I can see one other immediately). But I'll leave you to find those out.